# Is $\Vert x \Vert_{H^m(\Omega)} = 1$ (Sobolev-norms) always a unit ball if you plot/visualise it it?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

We know that for $L^p$ norms one gets a fascinating visual display of the norms as included. Do the Sobolev norms follow the same or a similar pattern or are they always unit balls? If they are always unit balls, are for example, $H^2(\Omega)$ norm balls smaller than those in $H^1(\Omega)$ because of the compact embedding theorem? Thank you very much for your time.

[image]

Comment: Cool question. I think you need to realize that those pictures of $l^p$ norms are plotted all in the same vector space, $\mathbf{R}^2$. That's why you can compare them like that. So where does your picture take place? Is there an infinite dimensional vector space on which you will plot the different Sobolev norms?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The fact that the norms were plotted in $\mathcal{R}^2$ makes a lot of sense. I am attempting to try and build a picture where I can compare $H^2(\Omega)$ to $H^1(\Omega)$. I know that $H^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^1(\Omega)$. I am attempting to show that an interpolation error in $H^1(\Omega)$ such that $\Vert u - u_h \Vert_{H_1}$ is bound in $H^2$ hence verifying/vlaidating the use of compact embedding theorem in the proof of the Bramble-Hilbert Lemma. I thought one way to go about this is to draw mapping between the two sobolev spaces.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2959837/539307

Comment: I posted that link. It is one of my previous questions that I am attempting to solve. I thought that If I knew the shapes of the Sobolev norms then I might be able to do that. Apologies for posting a link to a previous question. I am not fishing for answers. I thought it would be the best way to explain the purpose of this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "are they always unit balls"? What is a ball? Basically the pattern for Sobolev spaces is the same as for $L^p$ spaces, in that the ones for $p=2$ are the only Hilbert spaces among them and the only ones with a smooth norm.  Get a book on Banach space geometry to see what this means, but it's basically what you think it means. Furthermore, if you believe  that linear isometries  preserve looks, the Sobolev spaces are isomorphic to $\ell^2$ and thus their unit balls really look exactly like the Euclidean unit balls.

Comment: None of this tells you anything how they look like relatively though. For intuition, the relative looks are similar to how weighted $\ell^2$ spaces and their unit balls look like ellipses within the standard Euclidean unit ball. This is because, after the linear isometry given by the Fourier transform, Sobolev spaces really all are weighted $L^2$ spaces

Comment: @Bananach Would you mind please posting your two comments as answers please. Your comments are precisely what I was looking for with additional information and the great idea of recommending a book. Thank you very much for your time, patience and understanding; it is greatly appreciated.